# Aggregate MYSQL functions getting a value in the same row

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions, max

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, MAX(date_time) FROM messages 
                      WHERE user_to='$current_user' OR user_from='$current_user'
                      GROUP BY conversation 
                      ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0,5") or die(mysql_error());

echo $message['MAX(date_time)'];
```

How can I display the column 'content' that is in the same row as the date_time being selected here, so the time matches with the message? Would it be something like

```
echo $message['MAX(content)'];
```

I am trying to have 'messages' in groups (called conversations) and I want to display the most recent message. It is currently displaying the most recent time but not the most recent message.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done some research on question? There are literally hundreds of questions here on SO related to your question

Comment: You shouldn't really use `... or die( sensitive information );` in production, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table has an **autoincrement** id column to use as the message id, then the highest id value should also be the latest message in the conversation

Answer (score 1):

Try Below:

```
SELECT * from messages as ts
LEFT JOIN (select max(id) as maxid from messages group by date_time) as tsm
ON ts.id=tsm.maxid  
WHERE (ts.user_to='$current_user' OR ts.user_from='$current_user')
ORDER BY ts.date_time DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Assuming id is `primary` key column in your message table

Answer (score 0):

Order your messages by date_time and only take the first tuple (`LIMIT 1`).
I don't get why you aggregate if you just want the latest tuple from messages. Perhaps you can elaborate this and provide some more information about the table.

```
SELECT content, date_time
FROM messages
WHERE user_to='$current_user' OR user_from='$current_user'
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have auto incrementing key, you can try:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages as m
                      WHERE user_to='$current_user' OR user_from='$current_user' AND 
                            id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages as m2 GROUP BY m2.conversation)
                      ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0,5") or die(mysql_error());
```